# How can I create this Switch behavior?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uistoryboard, uiswitch

I want to create the following selection button to pick from the two options "Salary" and "Hourly Wage".

[image]

I have images for when either (left or right) option are selected.

[image]

What UI element in iOS can I use to create this? Looked into a [Switch](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwitch_Class/index.html) but did not see an option on how to set custom backgrounds.

Obv in code I will need to know which option is selected also. Should I be treating these as two separate `UIButton`s right next to each other?

Comment: The control you are looking for is a UISegmentedControl - see the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/).

Comment: Yes, perfect... new to iOS so didn't know. Your comment should be the answer here, change it and I will mark it as the answer, thanks.

Comment: Knowing the right terminology is half the problem!  The [UIKit User Interface Catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/index.html) is a good resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The control you are looking for is a UISegmentedControl - see the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/).